# Marketo munchkin.js calls returning no response intermittently. (CORS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, marketo

When calling the Marketo munchkin.js we are seeing intermittent XHR/CORS errors. This does not happen on every request it is very spotty. Getting into Heisenbug territory.

The specific response from Firefox was:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at XYZ.mktoresp.com/webevents/visitWebPage?XYZ 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Marketo has informed us that we need to enable CORS on our server for their domain, which we did and we are still seeing issue. The confusing thing is these are GET requests which are allowed without CORS. These are not POST methods, they either specifically call Marketos munchkin.js tracking function visitWebPage (GET), which return in the response a tracking pixel 1x1 png.

The confusing part is we made no server configuration changes on any of our environments, this was confirmed by our SCM.  We are seeing this issue on multiple sites on different platforms/hosts. We have also tested the simple munchkin.js calls and the jQuery.ajax calls.

If anyone else in the community is seeing this please let me know.

Comment: Was able to reproduce this error on multiple environments, networks and technologies. Static HTML vs Drupal CMS vs Other Serverside technologies and we are getting the same result.

Comment: We are also seeing that marketo is loading two versions of the munchkin.js script in every implementation that we have tested from the trivial to the complex. Which is a weird behavior for their script.

Comment: We have enabled CORS and Marketo is telling us that we have to enable CORS. If we find a solution we will post it here, because Marketo is not acknowledging this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am the developer for Munchkin.js at Marketo Inc.

The CORS errors reported by Firebug do not interfere with any Munchkin/Page functionality. They are caused by an optimization in the current version of munchkin which tries to release the XHR connection as soon as it has reported the page activity to Marketo. Firebug mis-reports this as a CORS error. Other browsers correctly report this as cancelled.

We currently planning to remove the optimization in a future release since a lot of customers seem concerned by both the CORS and cancelled messages.